# Extending as.data.frame and as.matrix methods for an object created via setRefClass

Tags: r, class, oop, methods, reference-class

I'm creating a reference class object in a manner similar to the example below:

```
# Class -------------------------------------------------------------------

myDataFrame <- setRefClass(Class = "myDataFrame",
                           fields = list(data = "data.frame",
                                         key_columns = "character"))

# Instance ----------------------------------------------------------------

myCars <- myDataFrame$new(data = mtcars,
                          key_columns = c("mpg", "cyl"))
```

I'm creating a `show` method for that class:

```
myDataFrame$methods(
    show = function() {
        cat(
            paste("Rows:", nrow(data)),
            paste("Cols:", ncol(data)),
            paste("Summary for key columns:", paste(key_columns, collapse = " ")),
            sep = "\n"
        )
        sapply(data[, key_columns], function(key_col) {
            print(summary(key_col))
        })
    }
)
```

this works as envisaged:

```
>> myCars
Rows: 32
Cols: 11
Summary for key columns: mpg cyl
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  10.40   15.43   19.20   20.09   22.80   33.90 
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  4.000   4.000   6.000   6.188   8.000   8.000
```

## Problem

I would like to extend this class with `as.matrix` and `as.data.frame` methods.

```
myDataFrame$methods(
    as.matrix = function() {
        as.matrix(data)
    }
)
```

This does not seem to work:

```
>> myCars$as.matrix()
Error in as.matrix(data) : unused argument (data)
>> as.matrix(myCars)
Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'any'
```

## Desired results

- For `as.matrix` in the context of the provided example the result should be equivalent to `as.matrix(mtcars)`
- For `as.data.frame` the result should be equivalent to `as.data.frame(mtcars[,c("mpg", "cyl")])` where the selected columns reflect `key_columns`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace for the as.matrix when your method name is called the same thing e.g.

```
myDataFrame$methods(
    as.matrix = function() {
        base::as.matrix(data)
    }
)
```